# Add tester in iTunes Connection

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We have a game in AppStore and send mail to publisher for review my game.
I receive this message from them:

> We need to see the iOS version, could you send us two codes from iTunes
>   connect so we can play it on our iOS devices.

How I can get this code in iTunes connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to iTunes Connect, select "Apps" and then the app you want to give a promo code of.

Scroll to the bottom and you will see the link: Promo Codes[image]